# HTC ONE X+ BLE with BlueGiga module

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

There have been some discussion about Android and BLE. Since Android do not have yet official support for BLE, other solutions are needed. Seems to be difficult to find combination to make BLE connection to Android (device-drivers-BLE chip).

There have been recommendations to use HTC One X+ and HTC BLE SDK (best available solution).

I have now HTC One X+, HTC BLE SDK and BlueGiga 112 evaluation board.

I have not been able to get connection with "Heart rate sample".

Before I continue work with these, I have simple question:
Have somebody succeeded with this combination (HTC One X+, HTC BLE SDK and BlueGiga 112 evaluation board / BlueGiga BLE module) ?

Answer (score 1):

I connected to BlueGiga at the Bluetooth Unplugfest with an HTC using the HTC BLE SDK. With FMP ( https://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/source/browse/#git%2FSamples%2FBleFindMeClient ), sending a high alert level then displayed "HIGH ALERT" on the LCD on the board. With HRM, they were able to send different values of heart rate with a control on the board. For the heart rate sample you may want to replace the connectBckground call with a connect call triggered by a button, then press the button several times watching the logs. There's a fixed broadcom stack that can be pushed by ADB after ADB remount, but for now a few connection retries are needed. The connectBackground call only tries once then waits a long time, then tries again, etc.. When doing the retries programatically, it isn't harmful to have an extra connection call after getting a success since it is just ignored.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the same I do for 2 bigger and much more complicated projects which are already on sale for iOS devices and we are working on Android support. Reading and Writing GATT characteristics works fine when the (foreground) Connection is established. There are nice debug traces about Service and Characteristics discovery.

Lance: any plans to update the broadcom stack in a future release for One X+?